# How to get the sum for each variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe named "spam_df" like this:

```
## # A tibble: 5,574 x 631
## # Groups:   df.is_spam [2]
##    df.is_spam    w_   w_.  w_.. w_..1 w_..2 w_..3 w_.amp. w_.lt...gt.
##    <lgl>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <int>       <int>
##  1 FALSE          8     0     0     0     0     0       0           0
##  2 FALSE          5     0     0     0     0     0       0           0
##  3 TRUE           1     0     0     0     0     0       0           0
##  4 FALSE          5     0     0     0     0     0       0           0
##  5 FALSE          1     0     0     0     0     0       0           0
##  6 TRUE           4     0     0     0     0     0       0           0
##  7 FALSE          1     0     0     0     0     0       0           0
##  8 FALSE          2     0     0     0     0     0       0           0
##  9 TRUE           5     0     0     0     0     0       0           0
## 10 TRUE           2     0     0     0     0     0       0           0
## # ... with 5,564 more rows, and 622 more variables: w_.lt.DECIMAL.gt. <int>,
## #   w_..4 <int>, w_Â.1 <int>, w_Â.100 <int>, w_Â.1000 <int>, w_Â.5000 <int>,
## #   w_000 <int>, w_1 <int>, w_10 <int>, w_150p <int>, w_150ppm <int>,
## #   w_16 <int>, w_16. <int>, w_18 <int>, w_1st <int>, w_2 <int>, w_2nd <int>,
## #   w_3 <int>, w_4 <int>, w_4. <int>, w_5 <int>, w_50 <int>, w_500 <int>,
## #   w_6 <int>, w_7 <int>, w_8 <int>, w_8007 <int>, w_9 <int>, w_a <int>,
## #   w_A <int>, w_able <int>, w_about <int>, w_abt <int>, w_account <int>, ...
```

For each variable that starts with "w_" I want to get the sum of its integer when df.is_spam is FALSE and when it is TRUE.

e.g for "w_" when df.is_spam is TRUE I got this:

```
spam_data<-spam.df %>% group_by(df.is_spam) %>% filter(df.is_spam=="TRUE")
spam_messages <- spam_data$w_
y_i<-sum(spam_messages)
y_i

2266
```

However there are 630 of those variables start with "w_", how do I calculate the sum for each without going through every one of them manually? TIA!

Comment: Do I just do spam_data<-spam.df %>% group_by(df.is_spam) %>% filter(df.is_spam=="TRUE") %>% summarise() ?

Comment: Sorry I am still confused and I don't know where to put my summarise() function. Also do I put in n=n() within the summarise() function?

Comment: Ok I solved mine without using any summarise(). I used colSums() instead.

Comment: If you want to do this with `summarise()` for some reason, you could use `summarise_at(vars(starts_with("w_")) ...)`.

Comment: Or, since `summarise_at` is a bit old fashioned, you could use `summarise(across(ends_with("t"), sum))`.